# RECORD COUNT in SQL with an ORDER BY, until a value is found in a column

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to get a row count from a recordset. My SQL knowledge is very limited, and I thought this query would be easier than it's turning out to be!

What I would like is to count the number of rows in the recordset, grouped by a common value in a column named "member_location", ordered by a column named "reputation_total_points" in **descending** order, until the parser reaches a result with a specific value in the "ID" column.

For example, if the query was using "member_location"= 10, and "id"= 2, the final correct count result will be **3** by using the info below. Below is a sample of the db entries:

Columns: id | reputation_total_points | member_location

2 | 32 | 10

3 | 35 | 7

4 | 40 | 10

5 | 15 | 5

6 | 10 | 10

7 | 65 | 10

Happy to elaborate further if needed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What the  result should be for "member_location"= 10 and "id" = 6 ?              Is it   4 or 1 ?

Comment: Hi DimaSUN!
The result for "member_location"= 10 and "id" = 6 should be 4.

If it also helps with the syntax, the actual database table name is "members".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @member_location int = 10
       ,@id int = 2;

-- CTE to populate data
with TestTable
as (
select *
from (
values
(2 , 32 , 10),
(3 , 35 , 7),
(4 , 40 , 10),
(5 , 15 , 5),
(6 , 10 , 10),
(7 , 65 , 10) ) V(id,reputation_total_points,member_location)
)
-- Main Query 
select 
    res.z 
from (
       select 
         id,
         z =  COUNT_BIG(*) over ( Order by  reputation_total_points desc )
        from TestTable
        where member_location = @member_location
      ) res
where id  = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of asking question is to explain what is the situation and what is desire.There is loophole in your logic and you will not get optimize query.

Try this,

```
declare @t table(id int, reputation_total_points int, member_location int)
insert into @t values
(2 , 32 , 10)
,(3 , 35 , 7 )
,(4 , 40 , 10)
,(5 , 15 , 5 )
,(6 , 10 , 10)
,(7 , 65 , 10)

DECLARE @RecordToBeFound INT = 10
DECLARE @UntilID INT = 2;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY reputation_total_points DESC
            ) rownum
    FROM @t
    )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE reputation_total_points <= (
        SELECT reputation_total_points
        FROM cte
        WHERE id = @UntilID
            AND member_location = @RecordToBeFound
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by something your query in order to get sum of something.

```
    select 
        member_location 
        , count(member_location) cnt
    from
        members
    where
        id > 2
        and member_location = 10
    group by
        member_location
    order by 
        2 desc
```

Answer (score -1):

You've tagged this question as Classic ASP/VBScript.  The ADODB.Recordset object which ASP uses has a property called Recordcount which you could use here.  Your code would look something like

```
dim conn

set conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=yourdatasource;User ID=yourid;Initial Catalog=yourdb;Password=yourpassword"
dim rs_sql
rs_sql="SELECT id, reputation_total_points, member_location from yourtable where id > 1 and member_location = 10 order by id desc"

dim rs
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.open rs_sql,conn,3,1

response.write rs.recordcount



rs.close
set rs = nothing
conn.close
set conn = nothing
```

I've used  "where id > 1" on the assumption that you want your "id = 2" row included in the results.  Your question is a little bit ambiguous on this

In "rs.open rs_sql,conn,3,1", the 3 and 1 denote a static cursor and read only lock type respectively.  Some cursor types do not support the recordcount property.  Also you need to use an OLEDB rather than an ODBC data provider.

Further information here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx